# Sets of coprime order (m,n) have period of (m • n), but why?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand the mathematical principles behind an algorithm I've created. I'll explain how it works practically:

The algorithm takes an integer as input and returns a string. In the algorthim there are two lists of strings. The lengths of these lists are relatively prime. We define list indexes by the input modulo the length of the given list. We create the output string by joining the strings found in both lists at the indexes.

Here's a trivial (pseudocode) example:

```
listA = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
listB = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple']

input = 13
indexA = 13 % listA.length()
indexB = 13 % listB.length()
firstPart = listA[indexA]
secondPart = listB[indexB]

result = "{firstPart}{secondPart}"
```

I understand that this as the input increases, this function simply loops through all possible combinations of the lists.

Now, put mathematically, I understand that I have two sets, M and N, with coprime order (|m|, |n|), and that if I count through them using modular arithmetic, the period is the full range of possible combinations (m • n), but, I don't fully understand why this is true if the sets are coprime in order (and isn't if they're not).

I'm not looking for a formal proof – just an explanation for why this works (or pointers to where I can find one). Lagrange's theorem and Fermat's little theorem both seem related and possibly applicable, but I don't understand them well enough to see how they would apply here.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement).

If $m$ and $n$ are not comprime, the selection for $k+\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}$ is the same as for $k$, so you only get one out of $\gcd(m,n)$ of all the combinations.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely helpful, but I still don't really see the connection between the Chinese remainer theorem, simultaneous congruences, and my algorthim. Specifically, I'm unsure where the k + (mn)/gcd(m,n) formula you provided comes from or what it implies?

Comment: @patr1ck: $mn/\gcd(m,n)$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$, the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$. This is relevant because you start over with both residues zero when you reach $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$ (since each residue is zero iff the index is a multiple of the respective list length). If $\gcd(m,n)$ is $1$ (i.e. they're coprime), then $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)=mn$, so you've cycled through all $mn$ possibilities before starting over. Otherwise, you start over after covering only $1$ out of $\gcd(m,n)$ of the possibilities.

Comment: @patr1ck: A good way to think about $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ is as $\min$ and $\max$, respectively, operating on the exponents of the primes. So e.g. $\gcd(m,n)\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)=mn$ is the analogue of $\min(x,y)+\max(x,y)=x+y$.